# Can I play Five Finger Fillet in Undead Nightmare?

Tags: xbox-360, red-dead-redemption

Can I play the Five Finger Fillet game in Undead Nightmare on the Xbox 360?
I know it is playable in the standard version but Undead Nightmare is somehow a standalone game on the Xbox 360.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [Five Finger Fillet](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Five_Finger_Fillet) is only available in the "base" game mode.  None of the gambling games are available in Undead Nightmare - there's not even money!